# Firebase user properties not summing up to number of active users

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

We recently started using Firebase `UserProperty` for our app analytics and it seems to be working quite well, except that for some properties the numbers of the possible values (mostly `true` and `false`) don't add up to the total number of active users displayed if Firebase for a certain day.

One example to make it more clear:

I select the date July 28th as the date and the total number of active 1-day users is 4.3k. Now I add the condition `auto_lock` which is a user property and can only be true or false. The number of users that has is enabled (= `true`) is 1.9k and the number of users that has is disabled (= `false`) is 1.3k. These are the only possible values, I can only select these 2 values in the Firebase Analytics Dashboard UI and I have no idea why the don't add up to the number of 4.3k. Users can opt-out of analytics of course, but if they do, they wouldn't be counted as active users and there is no case in code where user properties are not set. In theory, the numbers for true and false should sum up to the same number as the active 1-day users.

Another one is, that when I add a comparison by device type and select all 3 available categories (mobile, tablet, tv) I get a total number of 3.3k again, whereas the total number of active users is still 4.3k.

Comment: IIRC the total active users count can be considered active devices. For example, if a user aggressively clears their cache every time their browser closes, uses a different browser/device, or views in private browsing, they will be treated as a new "active user" each time they visit your site.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that would be quite misleading if they call it "Active users" and it's actually active devices. And if they clear the cache every time they close the app, the user property will be set again after the next start.

Comment: so, you looked at the data at least a day or few afterwards? it can take some time for collected data to be consolidated. but again, i'm not too surprised the numbers don't match.

Comment: Yes, they also sum up for a time range of 3, 5 or 7 days. And I am actually surprised that they don't sum up. I mean, it's okay as long as I understand which is the actual number of active users. 4.3k or 3.3k. It's quite a big difference.